# Skipping header rows in AWS Redshift External Tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a file in S3 with the following data:

```
name,age,gender
jill,30,f
jack,32,m
```

And a redshift [external table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html) to query that data using [spectrum](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/spectrum/):

```
create external table spectrum.customers ( 
 "name" varchar(50),
 "age" int,
 "gender" varchar(1))
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by \n'
stored as textfile 
location 's3://...';
```

When querying the data I get the following result:

```
select * from spectrum.customers;
name,age,g
jill,30,f
jack,32,m
```

Is there an elegant way to skip the header row as part of the external table definition, similar to the `tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")` option in Hive? Or is my only option (at least for now) to filter out the header rows as part of the select statement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answered this in: [How to skip headers when we are reading data from a csv file in s3 and creating a table in aws athena.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488792/how-to-skip-headers-when-we-are-reading-data-from-a-csv-file-in-s3-and-creating/47723304#47723304)

This works in Redshift:

You want to use `table properties ('skip.header.line.count'='1')`
Along with other properties if you want, e.g. `'numRows'='100'`.
Here's a sample:

```
create external table exreddb1.test_table
(ID BIGINT 
,NAME VARCHAR
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location 's3://mybucket/myfolder/'
table properties ('numRows'='100', 'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

Comment: Here's AWS Redshift SQL documentation on "Create External Table", http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html

Answer (score 3):

Currently, AWS Redshift Spectrum does not support skipping header rows. If you can, you could raise a support issue that would allow tracking the availability of this feature.

It would be possible to forward this request to the development team for consideration.

Comment: Have a look at @TheWalkingData's answer - it is possible now (was probably added in the mean time).