# How to skip headers when we are reading data from a csv file in s3 and creating a table in aws athena.

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to read csv data from s3 bucket and creating a table in AWS Athena. My table when created was unable to skip the header information of my CSV file.

Query Example :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (   `event_type_id`
     string,   `customer_id` string,   `date` string,   `email` string )
     ROW FORMAT SERDE  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
     WITH
     SERDEPROPERTIES (   "separatorChar" = "|",   "quoteChar"     = "\"" )
     LOCATION 's3://location/' 
     TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

skip.header.line.count doesn't seem to work.
But this does not work out. I think Aws has some issue with this.Is there any other way that I could get through this?

Comment: I just tried this today in Athena, and it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what works in Redshift:

You want to use `table properties ('skip.header.line.count'='1')`
Along with other properties if you want, e.g. `'numRows'='100'`.
Here's a sample:

```
create external table exreddb1.test_table
(ID BIGINT 
,NAME VARCHAR
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location 's3://mybucket/myfolder/'
table properties ('numRows'='100', 'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

Comment: Here's AWS Redshift SQL documentation on "Create External Table", http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a known deficiency.

The best method I've seen was [tweeted by Eric Hammond](https://twitter.com/esh/status/811396849756041217?lang=en):

```
...WHERE date NOT LIKE '#%'
```

This appears to skip header lines during a Query. I'm not sure how it works, but it might be a method for skipping NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (2019-11-18), the query from the OP seems to work. i.e. `skip.header.line.count` is honored and the first line is indeed skipped.